# Were Texas & Florida Hiding COVID-19 Data?

Tags: united-states, politics, covid-19

I remember reading that Texas and Florida (which have some high population density cities (and especially Florida with a high percentage of elderly, and hence at risk population) were not comparable as far as COVID-19 deaths or infections per capita which has led to some speculating against the scientific consensus that masks are efficacious against the virus (although varying degrees of protection depending on mask type).

Was there a change of government policy effecting the honest reporting of the numbers for the high population density regions of Florida and Texas to make it appear that numbers were lower than they actually were?

Comment: Do you have a notable claim you can cite which needs challenging. This seems like a straight question about the effects of govt. policy at the moment.

Comment: Might be a suitable question on https://politics.stackexchange.com/ or https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/